# Trying intent extras to restore string value into textview

Tags: java, android

I'm quite new to programming in android studio and can't seem to make my application restore an intent value into a textview.

I have a questions activity where a user is asked some questions, these are answered using yes/no radio buttons. From here a advanced diagnosis is already made, so the diagnosis is stored in the questions activity into my 'storeintent()' method. The problem is that when the intent is called into the answers activity using the 'restoreintents()' method nothing shows up in the textview.

Here is the Questions activity (where the answer is already stored, please view comments made):

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Questions extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button2;

private RadioButton radioButton;
private RadioButton radioButton2;
private RadioButton radioButton3;
private RadioButton radioButton4;
private RadioButton radioButton5;
private RadioButton radioButton6;
private RadioButton radioButton7;
private RadioButton radioButton8;
private RadioButton radioButton9;
private RadioButton radioButton10;
private RadioButton radioButton11;
private RadioButton radioButton12;
private RadioButton radioButton13;
private RadioButton radioButton14;
private RadioButton radioButton15;
private RadioButton radioButton16;
private RadioButton radioButton17;
private RadioButton radioButton18;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);

    storeintent();

    button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            opendiagnosis();
            storeintent();
        }
    });

    //Question 1
    radioButton = findViewById(R.id.radioButton); //yes
    radioButton2 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton20); //no
    //Question 2
    radioButton3 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton4); //yes
    radioButton4 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton2); //no
    //Question 3
    radioButton5 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton6); //yes
    radioButton6 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton5); //no
    //Question 4
    radioButton7 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton7); //yes
    radioButton8 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton8); //no
    //Question 5
    radioButton9 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton9); //yes
    radioButton10 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton10); //no
    //Question 6
    radioButton11 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton12); //yes
    radioButton12 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton11); //no
    //Question 7
    radioButton13 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton13); //yes
    radioButton14 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton14); //no
    //Question 8
    radioButton15 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton15); //yes
    radioButton16 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton16); //no
    //Question 9
    radioButton17 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton17); //yes
    radioButton18 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton18); //no
}

public void storeintent() {

    String value="Android Studio Is TERRIBLE"; //my string to be displayed in textView16 in the answers activity
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Questions.class);
    i.putExtra("key",value);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void opendiagnosis() {
    // for all pairs: one of each pair has to be checked
    boolean shouldStartNextActivity = (radioButton.isChecked() || radioButton2.isChecked())
            && (radioButton3.isChecked() || radioButton4.isChecked()) && (radioButton5.isChecked() || radioButton6.isChecked())
            && (radioButton7.isChecked() || radioButton8.isChecked())&& (radioButton9.isChecked() || radioButton10.isChecked())
            && (radioButton11.isChecked() || radioButton12.isChecked())&& (radioButton13.isChecked() || radioButton14.isChecked())
            && (radioButton15.isChecked() || radioButton16.isChecked())&& (radioButton17.isChecked() || radioButton18.isChecked());


    if (shouldStartNextActivity){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, answers.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please answer all the questions for an accurate diagnosis", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);


    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption1", radioButton.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption2", radioButton2.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption3", radioButton3.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption4", radioButton4.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption5", radioButton5.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption6", radioButton6.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption7", radioButton7.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption8", radioButton8.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption9", radioButton9.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption10", radioButton10.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption11", radioButton11.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption12", radioButton12.isChecked());
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    radioButton.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption1"));
    radioButton2.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption2"));
    radioButton3.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption3"));
    radioButton4.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption4"));
    radioButton5.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption5"));
    radioButton6.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption6"));
    radioButton7.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption7"));
    radioButton8.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption8"));
    radioButton9.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption9"));
    radioButton10.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption10"));
    radioButton11.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption11"));
    radioButton12.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption12"));

}
}
```

Here is the Answers activity (where the diagnosis is meant to be retrieved by calling the intent, but is not, please refer to comments made):

```
public class answers extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button7;


private TextView textView;
private TextView textView2;
private TextView textView3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answers);

    restoreintents(); //method CALLED HERE!

    button7 = findViewById(R.id.button7);
    button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            reset();
        }
    });


    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView16);
    textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView17);
    textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView18);
}

public void restoreintents() {

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); //Questions intent is called here again
    if (extras != null) {
        String value = extras.getString("key");
        //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity

        textView.setText(value); //String does not appear in textbox, it stays empty
    }
}


public void reset() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Questions.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use intent.putExtra(key, value) and then get these sent information in your destination activity and fetch them with getExtra(key) function.
you can do it like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);   
String value  = "some string";
i.putExtra("KEY_STRING", value );
```

and get it in MyActivity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle.getString("KEY_STRING")!= null) {
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("KEY_STRING");
}
```

Comment: How would I call the string value in the my activity section? Thank you for the help so far

Comment: @DaMafiaGamer I edited the answer. you can see how to get your string in if block

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass value to answers class, replace below code in question class

```
if (shouldStartNextActivity){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, answers.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", value);
    startActivity(intent);
} else{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please answer all the questions for an accurate diagnosis", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Same way you also need to put extras in answers class

```
public void reset() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Questions.class);
     intent.putExtra("key", textView.getText());
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: It says cannot resolve symbol value, what am I doing wrong

Comment: "value" is whatever you want to pass for example in answers class intent.putExtra("key", textView.getText()), value is textView.getText()

Comment: Ok, just figured it out, the application crashes though. Seems like I may need to find another way. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to adding an extra to Intent in `opendiagnosis()` method 
change your code as following:

```
public void opendiagnosis() {
// for all pairs: one of each pair has to be checked
boolean shouldStartNextActivity = (radioButton.isChecked() || radioButton2.isChecked())
        && (radioButton3.isChecked() || radioButton4.isChecked()) && (radioButton5.isChecked() || radioButton6.isChecked())
        && (radioButton7.isChecked() || radioButton8.isChecked())&& (radioButton9.isChecked() || radioButton10.isChecked())
        && (radioButton11.isChecked() || radioButton12.isChecked())&& (radioButton13.isChecked() || radioButton14.isChecked())
        && (radioButton15.isChecked() || radioButton16.isChecked())&& (radioButton17.isChecked() || radioButton18.isChecked());


if (shouldStartNextActivity){
   String value="Android Studio Is TERRIBLE"; 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, answers.class);
    intent.putExtra("key",value);
    startActivity(intent);
} else{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please answer all the questions for an accurate 
diagnosis", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
  }
```